# How to use the API to download a repo

Tags: git, api, repository, bitbucket, swisscomdev

I want to download a single file from my Bitbucket repository. In the [documentary](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/repository-resource-1-0-296095202.html#repositoryResource1.0-GETtherawsource) I found the following API call.

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/{accountname}/{repo_slug}/raw/{revision}/{path}
```

However I struggle to find out what my "accountname", "repo_slug", "revision" and "path" is.

If I open the folder "scripts" in my Bitbucket account the browser displays the following link.

```
https://example.com/projects/MMMA/repos/iapc_reporting/browse/scripts
```

For accountname I used "MMMA", for repo_slug "iapc_reporting", for revision the branch "master", and for path "scripts/main.py". The URL now looks like this:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/MMMA/iapc_reporting/raw/master/scripts/main.py
```

Unfortunately opening this link in my browser gives me an 404 error. How do I properly buidl this link? If you had a solution with the V2 API that would be even better.

Comment: Is this a private repo?

Comment: Yes, I tried curl --user user:pw https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/MMMA/iapc_reporting/raw/master/scripts/main.py.

Comment: And does https://bitbucket.org/MMMA/iapc_reporting exists? Can you access that url?

Comment: No, it does not. I get the 404 error again.

Comment: Do you know the bitbucket url of your private repo?

Answer (score 1):

If your server "example.com" is managed by a BitBucket server, then the API url should be:

```
https://example.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/MMMA/repos/iapc_reporting
```

See "[Bitbucket Server REST APIs](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/server/docs/latest/how-tos/command-line-rest.html)".

In your case, since it is a private repo, with a `curl --user user:pw`:

```
https://example.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/MMMA/repos/iapc_reporting/raw/master/scripts/main.py
```

Comment: Unfortunately this leads to a 404 error page in an xml format.

Comment: @user3080315 Unless you have an old version of BitBucket as a server, this is the correct syntax, as documented in https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/server/docs/latest/how-tos/command-line-rest.html

Comment: @user3080315 Do you at least access https://example.com/rest/api/1.0/ ?

Comment: Shows me the same page. Is that even possible that my company set up Bitbucket without the API?

Comment: @user3080315 That possible, check with your IT support department.

Comment: I looked it up and is installed. I tried to do this curl -u username:password https://example.com/projects/MMMA/repos/iapc_reporting/browse/scripts/main.py?raw and it actually shows me the whole content of the main.py my cmd console. What do you think about that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148591/discussion-between-vonc-and-user3080315).

Comment: That is the URL seen by the user in the BitBucket web page. That does not use directly the API.